# iOS 6 inApp issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase, ios6

Anyone used iOS6 inApp purchase? My inApp was working fine on iOS5 but when i am tying to build my app in iOS6 (XCode 4.5 beta). It is showing below error while inApp purchase.

2012-10-06 15:13:49.653 failed transaction
2012-10-06 15:13:49.654 The error description is:Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x9caec40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

I have created another test user account but problem is still same. Also, tried with restarting XCode, Mac machine, simulator, reset simulator. Please help!!

FIX : Delete all inApp ids and create new. It will fix the issue.

Comment: are u sure your ipad is connected to internet?

Comment: Yes of course :) it is showing step upto "Confirm your inApp purchase" in both Simulator and Device.

Comment: Sign out and Sign in again in iTunes Connect on your device!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test In-App. purchase on simulator. If you tried to do that you will get the Confirm alert, but nothing will happen.

I had similar issue with iOS 6, I done the following procedures to fix it:

- Deleted my application from IPad
- Signed out from the stores
- Installed my application again
- Tested the In-App

It worked fine for me, make sure that the internet connection is there. If you had the problem again, just sign-out from the stores and again test In-App purchase. (when I got the error again after few In-App purchases, I done this too)

Comment: Hi All, I have deleted all inApp id from iTunes and created new one. Now it is working fine :)